# How to set up my grails logging configuration to show everything

Tags: logging, configuration, grails, log4j, package

I've set up several packages in my grails application to log to certain files (like `'org.codehaus.groovy.grails.plugins'` for example).

Now [I just experienced](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4224484/why-do-grails-quartz-jobs-die-after-a-few-minutes-on-production) that I've missed out on some exceptions from the quartz Jobs added via plug-in, because I didn't have the package `org.quartz` configured in my logger configuration (although I had the logger above for grails plugins included).

Of course I can add this now, but I want to make sure that in the future I see all Errors etc. that can happen in my application.

So how can I add a configuration for everything I've not explicitly included? Is there something like `*` that I can use in my logging configuration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yeah, in log4j speak it's called the root logger. See the documentation here:

http://grails.org/doc/1.1.x/guide/3.%20Configuration.html#3.1.2%20Logging

```
root {
    error()
}
```